# How do I repair cracks in thincoat plaster?

Tags: drywall, plaster, texture

I have a crack in the thincoat plaster that is over the drywall. There is an orange peel texture over the thincoat. What is this caused by, and what is the best way to repair it?

[image: Here is a picture of my problem]

Comment: That is the start of a window.

Comment: Can you post a wider angle picture, including the window frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That crack is most likely directly inline with a seam between two sections of the underlying drywall. Environmental effects or settling of the building structure over years can lead to cracks like this opening up.

Probably the best fix for this is to sand to roughen up the area for six to eight inches or so on either side of the crack. Then apply some good quality mesh style drywall joint tape:

[image]

(I would actually install in two overlapping layers).

Then use a drywall mud knife to embed the tape into a layer of drywall mud that is feathered out over a wide area on either side of the mesh tape. If the drywall mud is installed carefully over multiple applications you can minimize the amount of sanding required.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, thank you very much!

Comment: That texture was most likely sprayed on, not rolled. Setting-type makes for a better joint, pre-mixed is more suited for new construction and bonding to bare drywall.

Comment: @Michael Karas - I'm sorry, but that just sounds sloppy and unprofessional to me. It's not that complicated to replicate the original process. In this case, it could probably be done with a cheap Wagner and a soupy mixture of mud. Or even flicked on with a brush - but rolled? No.

Comment: @ Michael Karas - Given that perfect is more often the norm in this field, than the exception - "fair" hardly seems the "fair" response to the question, or "fair" to the rest of us who do this for a living. More information is obviously needed to answer this question appropriately, as the underlying cause most likely has more to do with the surrounding framing, than the drywall itself.

Comment: @ Michael Karas - There is no divide, between the desired results of a DIY'er and a Pro. Telling someone else to do shoddy work, because you are OK with it, is just bad form altogether.